# What are these programs called ? And what is the purpose?

Tags: c++

I came accross this C code.. Can anyone tell me what is this used for?

```
main()
{
    char*s="‎#include<iostream.h>%c
    main()
    {
        char*s=%c%s%c;
        cout.form(s,10,34,s,34,10);
    }
    %c";

    cout.form(s,10,34,s,34,10);
}


#include<iostream.h>
```

Comment: That looks like a quine.

Comment: @SLaks: ahhhh....that's the answer I was looking for..!! :P
Thanx a ton maitey..!! :D

Comment: I didn't knew anything about this, just started learning C :-), amazing thingy, no doubt... +1 to the question and all answers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet this program prints a copy of itself when run... check out wikipedia on quines: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)

Answer (score 2):

It's an auto-reproducing program: executing it will produce, as output, the exact same program as the source code of himself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a program that reads out his own source code.